# Cropping borders from images without invalidating georeferencing using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, georeferencing, aerial-photography

I am using ArcGIS Pro2.4.

I have a large collection of georeferenced historical aerials.  They all have borders of varying dimensions and varying shades of grey.  These borders have to go somehow.  I'd like to crop out the borders using a raster editing program as this seems simplest and quickest, provided I can preserve the georeferencing.

Is there any way to do this crop that won't mess up the georeferencing?

Comment: Georeferencing usually applies to the whole image including the borders and cropping the image is also changing the georeferencing (for example, top left corner is marked to have some known coordinates but after cropping the top left corner is not there). I recommend to use GIS software for cropping. ArcGIS Pro should be fine as well as QGIS.

Comment: So as long as I don't crop out any of the control point areas then the image should remain properly georeferenced?  The size of the image collection and them already being georeferenced (and hence rotated at various odd angles when brought into GIS) makes me think raster editors would be faster.

Comment: Very often, but not always, the control points are at the physical limits of the raster image. We don't have your data so we cannot say what you have.